# Accessing column value within loc gives error "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns of interest, `station` and `hall`, where a hall has multiple stations.  I want to filter the dataframe so that I only keep certain stations for each hall.

So for every row in the dataframe, keep it only if `hall == A and station in [A1, A2, A3] or hall == B and station in [B1, B3, B5] or ....`

As an example, if this was the starting df

```
Date   Meal   Hall     Station      Food
04/10  lunch  de neve  the grill    pizza
04/10  lunch  de neve  the kitchen  burger
04/10  lunch  covel    the oven     hot dog
04/10  lunch  covel    the kitchen  pasta
```

and I wanted to only keep `the grill` for de neve and `the oven` for covel, I should end up with

```
Date   Meal   Hall     Station      Food
04/10  lunch  de neve  the grill    pizza
04/10  lunch  covel    the oven     hot dog
```

I created a dictionary that captures the stations I want to keep for each hall

```
essential_stations = 
    {'HallA': [station1, station2],
     'HallB': [station3, station4],
     'HallC': [station5, station6],
    }
```

However when I execute the following

```
summary_food_df = food_df[food_df['station'].isin(essential_stations[food_df['hall']])]
```

I get the error

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Is there another way to filter out the extra stations using the dictionary?

Comment: pandas and python version?

Comment: You're trying to lookup a key in your dict using `food_df['hall']` this won't work, you need to pass a scalar value so what is `food_df['hall']` exactly? What are you trying to do as there is likely to be a better way

Comment: @EdChum `hall` and `station` are both strings.  For each hall, I want to keep only certain station values, so I captured that through the dictionary.

Comment: So does `food_df['hall']` just contain strings that are one of the keys in your dict? or is it something else? Please edit your question with raw data, full code to recreate your dfs, your attempts, and desired output

Comment: Yes, that interpretation is correct

Comment: So for every row in the dataframe, keep it only if `hall == A and station in [A1, A2, A3]  or hall == B and station in [B1, B3, B5] or ....`

Comment: @Mahir - Can you add some data samples with desired output?

Comment: @jezrael updated

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '04/10', 1: '04/10', 2: '04/10', 3: '04/10'},
 'Food': {0: 'pizza', 1: 'burger', 2: ' hot dog', 3: 'pasta'},
 'Hall': {0: 'de neve', 1: 'de neve', 2: 'covel', 3: 'covel'},
 'Meal': {0: 'lunch', 1: 'lunch', 2: 'lunch', 3: 'lunch'},
 'Station': {0: 'the grill',
  1: 'the kitchen',
  2: 'the oven',
  3: 'the kitchen'}})
essential_stations = {'de neve': ['the grill'], 'covel': ['the oven']}
# user apply to filter rows which satisfiy the condition (only certain stations for a hall)
df.apply(lambda x: x if x.Station in essential_stations.get(x.Hall) else np.nan, axis=1).dropna()
Out[265]: 
    Date      Food     Hall   Meal    Station
0  04/10     pizza  de neve  lunch  the grill
2  04/10   hot dog    covel  lunch   the oven
```